# Python documentation on possibly inherited method

Tags: python, object, methods

I am writing a program (python Python 3.5.2)  that uses a HTTPSConnection to get a JSON object as a response. I have it working using some example code, but am not sure where a method comes from. 
My question is this: In the code below, the decode('utf-9') method doesn't exist in the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse under "21.12.2. HTTPResponse Objects". How would I know that the return value from the method "response.read()" has the method "decode('utf-8')" available?

Do Python objects inherit from a base class like C# objects do or am I missing something?

```
http = HTTPSConnection(get_hostname(token))
http.request('GET', uri_path, headers=get_authorization_header(token))
response = http.getresponse()

print(response.status, response.reason)
feed = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `HTTPResponse.read()` returns a `bytes` object - this isn't very clear from the documentation, but there really isn't anything else it could be.  `.decode()` is a method of `bytes`, and has no connection to `HTTPResponse`.

Comment: The [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Lib/http/client.py#L526) makes it pretty clear that a `bytes` object is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `read` method of the response object always returns a byte string (in Python 3, which I presume you are using as you use the print function). The byte string does indeed have a `decode` method, so there should be no problem with this code. Of course it makes the assumption that the response is encoded in UTF-8, which may or may not be correct.

[Technical note: email is a very difficult medium to handle: messages can be made up of different parts, each of which is differently encoded. At least with web traffic you stand a chance of reading the `Content-Type` header's `charset` attribute to find the correct encoding].

Comment: Thank you! That does explain it. I sure wish the documentation would have some sort of link I could have followed to get to that information, it makes me wander if I won't run into a similar situation in the future. This code is actually from Sharefile's API. I have other code that acts as an SMTP server that will receive from a system where I know what kind of attachments will be sent, so I'm pretty much only accepting parts with that have file extensions that exists in a list. Eventually I'm just going to slap it all together with some logging.

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't been using Python long enough yet to understand the value of the interactive interpreter. Being able to try things, query the types of return value, and so on can really help you learn what's going on in your code. "Programming with a trowel" is a perfectly valid way to learn, but you may want to look more deeply into the language to improve your productivity as you go.

Comment: Oh, and you may want to look at the [`requests`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/) library - it's much easier to use than `http.client`. That's one disadvantage of just lifting examples - the author may not have been that well-versed in Python, and just needing a "working" example.

Comment: Thank you, most of the development I have done in the past was using Perl. I am relatively new to Python and am learning my way around as I go. I, unfortunately, find myself in the position of needing to get things done in a hurry, and my job requires me to wear a lot of hats and limits me in how I can focus on one particular subject. I don't like it as I don't get a complete education on things and it is somewhat frustrating. I will focus on the interactive interpreter as I kind of brushed it off as just interesting, but I can definitely see the value in it now.